# Testing transformer polarity with a signal generator and an oscilloscope

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, polarity

[image]

When using the above test setup to measure transformer polarity, the output on my oscilloscope shows a flat line at 0V, it does not register the waveform from the signal generator. The output on channel 2 is the same thing. If I leave the transformer windings floating (not connected to ground), I see the waveform clearly, but channel 1 and channel 2 end up with the same waveform regardless if I switch the test points on channel 2.

It makes sense to me because if connect the transformer to ground the signal is just going to ground out. But then why is the above test up the recommended set up? How do I get it to show me the dot phase of my transformer?

Comment: Try 1 kHz instead of what you used (presumably 50/60 Hz?)

Comment: Can you include a picture of your setup, with all connections visible (if possible), the scope image(s) and details about your signal generator (i.e. the test frequency)?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can try is testing it this way, connect the transformer as an [auto-transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer). Connect one  of the primary wires to one of the secondary wires and apply your signal across the primary. Use your scope to compare the signal level across the primary to the signal level at the open end of the secondary. If signal B is greater than A the windings are in series adding and phase dots would be at 1 and 4, if B is less than A they're series opposing and phase dots would be 1 and 3. You may need to have a load so the secondary isn't just going into a high impedance, I'm thinking something like 1k, but I'm not sure what would be best or if it's needed at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv4QB0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>